# Export-CSV with the output path as a variable

Tags: powershell

Is there a way I can export the list to a text file and separate them by share name somehow, not single file?

I'd like to do in this format, `"$hostname-$sharename.txt".`

Here is what I have so far:

```
$Shares = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Filter "not name like '%$'"  |
          Select-Object -Expand Path

$re = ($Shares | ForEach-Object {[Regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
$results = foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
    (Get-ChildItem $Share -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand FullName) -replace "^($re)\\"
}
$results | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Output\$($env:computername)-$sharename.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you are missing in your code is the sharename part for the various output files.

Below will hopefully do what you want:

```
$outputDir = 'C:\Output'
$Shares    = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Filter "not name like '%$'"

$re = ($Shares | ForEach-Object {[Regex]::Escape($_.Path)}) -join '|'
foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
    $result  = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Share.Path -File -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand FullName) -replace "^($re)\\"
    # output the results per share in a text file
    $fileOut = Join-Path -Path $outputDir -ChildPath ('{0}-{1}.txt' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $Share.Name)
    $result | Out-File -FilePath $fileOut -Force
}
```